# Crystal report shows white background color

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using Crystal report for showing report. I have set a common background color for the report. But in the details section has only one row, then that row has the background color which I set. The remaining portion is shown as a white background.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand you correctly, but it seems you want to change the background color of the entire report at once?

If so, I don't know if that's possible. Crystal doesn't give us an easy way to do that.

You will have to change the color of each section one by one to accomplish what you need.

**Here is how:**

1) Right click on the report, then go to 'Section Expert', then 'Color' and pick your background color ony by one, for each section for all sections.

2) After that, you need to change you Page configuration, from Pixels to Centimeters, then you inform 0 (zero) to all margins like the image below.

[image]

3) Done, now your report has just one background color, grey for example.

[image]